# Can't open connection with database in C# SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis, ssms, database-connection

I'm working with SSIS 2019 and with SSMS as my database. I wrote a script in SSIS in C# and it can't for some reason make a connection to my database.
I manage to see what's the problematic line and its the line with ** (see in code section). This line just bring me null no matter what. The variables I gave this code are right and I double checked that. its something small that I'm missing.

If you have any insight, I Would be glad to hear.

Error raised:

```
SSIS package "C:\Users\shale\source\repos\Integration Services Project3\Integration 
Services Project3\CompareCoulmnsNames.dtsx" starting.
Error: 0x0 at Script Task, Exception from Script Task: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection 
property has not been initialized.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 
completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, 
Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at ST_0802b46cfde44ff192edd969586bd834.ScriptMain.Main()
Warning: 0x80019002 at Script Task: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  
The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum 
allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the 
number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
Task failed: Script Task
Warning: 0x80019002 at Foreach Loop Container: SSIS Warning Code 
DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of 
errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs 
when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the 
MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
Warning: 0x80019002 at Package1: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The 
Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum 
allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the 
number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "C:\Users\shale\source\repos\Integration Services Project3\Integration 
Services Project3\CompareCoulmnsNames.dtsx" finished: Failure.
The program '[3020] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Here's the code:

```
public void Main()
    {
        
        string strPath1 = Dts.Variables["File1_PATH"].Value.ToString();
        if (File.Exists(strPath1))
        {
            string[] file1 = File.ReadAllLines(strPath1);
            Dts.Variables["COLUMN_NAMES"].Value = file1[0];
        }
        string strArr1 = Dts.Variables["COLUMN_NAMES"].Value.ToString();

        string strPath2 = Dts.Variables["FilesPath"].Value.ToString();
        string[] strArr2 = File.ReadAllLines(strPath2);

        
        DateTime loadingDateTime = new DateTime();
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(strPath2);
        int records = 0;
        string status = "";
       
        if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(strArr1, strArr2[0]))
        {
            Dts.Variables["BooleanVar"].Value = true;
            try
            {

                int counter = 0;
                
                string TableName = Dts.Variables["TABLE_NAME"].Value.ToString();
                **SqlConnection conn = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections[Dts.Variables["CONNECTION_MANAGER"].Value.ToString()].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);**
                // Check the connection state
                if (conn == null) { MessageBox.Show("null");  }
                foreach (string i in strArr2)
                {
                    
                    if (counter != 0)
                    {  
                        string query = "Insert into " + TableName + " values('" + i.Replace(",", "','").Replace("   ", "','") + "')";
                        
                        SqlCommand SQLCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                        SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        
                        
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                //change the current file data
                loadingDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                records = counter - 1;
                status = "Processed";

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Exception from Script Task", ex.Message + "\r" + ex.StackTrace, String.Empty, 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Dts.Variables["BooleanVar"].Value = false;
            status = "Wrong";
        }
        //insert the file data to etl_report
        string dest = Dts.Variables["DEST_PATH"].Value.ToString();
        string data = fileName + "," + status + "," + records.ToString() + "," + loadingDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt");

        if (!File.Exists(dest))
        {
            string clientHeader = "Filename" + "," + "Status" + "," + "Records" + "," + "LoadingDateTime" + Environment.NewLine;
            File.WriteAllText(dest, clientHeader);
        }
        File.AppendAllText(dest, data + Environment.NewLine);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Comment: you need  open DB(conn.open)

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi. I can't because conn is null and null doesn't have open() function. it's not solving the problem.

Comment: I think it gives an error at runtime(Line   SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();). So try this code  before line "foreach (string i in strArr2)"
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();

Comment: when i gave conn his first value it returns null so i cant work with conn at all. its just null. @abolfazlsadeghi
(SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections[Dts.Variables["CONNECTION_MANAGER"]...
this line returns null so conn is also null... if that line would return the value needed to conn that will solve my problem.

Comment: why you use AcquireConnection. 
you use sqlconnection directly and use bulkinsert

Comment: I'll be honest. that's a line i found at stack overflow. can you write for me the right line as you see as right?

Comment: Please try this code. If you want, I will also send you the bulk code.only you send connection string.You will send the connection with the variable

Answer (score 1):

you must use this code
my code(correct Code):

```
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Your connectionstring);
//example connectionstring :"Password=123;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sad;Initial Catalog=TestDB1;Data Source=.;TrustServerCertificate=True"
  // Check the connection state                  
  if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();
```

your code

```
                **SqlConnection conn = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections[Dts.Variables["CONNECTION_MANAGER"].Value.ToString()].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);**
                // Check the connection state
                if (conn == null) { MessageBox.Show("null");  }
```

Comment: its not working for me. the weird thing is that on my friend computer it's running just fine.

Comment: Maybe you don't have permission with engine sql destination or a services doesn't install(.Net or integration services and etc) or something is wrong on your system?first  check permission  or  services  then please  send your error to me

Answer (score 0):

you need to open your connection after the line

```
// Check the connection state
    if (conn == null)
     { 
      MessageBox.Show("null");      
     }
    else
    {
    conn.Open();
    }
```